# WIA Shared Samples - Translating VB to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, wia

This Sample is supposed to return the number of Root-Level Items for Transfer of any given Device ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wiaaut/-wiaaut-shared-samples#count-root-level-images-for-transfer)).

```
Dim d 'As Device
Dim itm 'As Item
Dim i 'As Integer

i = 0
Set d = CommonDialog1.ShowSelectDevice
For Each itm In d.Items
    Dim f
    f = itm.Properties("Item Flags")
    If (f And ImageItemFlag) = ImageItemFlag Then
       i = i + 1
    End If
Next

MsgBox "Selected device has " & i & " top-level images"
```

What troubles me is the following line:

```
If (f And ImageItemFlag) = ImageItemFlag Then
```

My Translation to C# is:

```
using static WIA.WiaItemFlag; // enum


Device device;
CommonDialog dialog = new CommonDialog();
int i = 0;

device = dialog.ShowSelectDevice();

foreach (Item item in device.Items)
{
    var property = item.Properties["Item Flags"];
    // &-Operator can't be applied to Types 'Property' and WiaItemFlag
    if ((property & ImageItemFlag).Equals(ImageItemFlag)) 
        i++;
}


//return i;
```

The Documentation [right here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wiaaut/-wiaaut-wiaitemflag) tells us that we can use the &-Operator indeed, but it doesn't work in practice.

How do you translate the If-Condition? I tried several times but the error is that one cannot use the '&'-Operator on Property and WiaItemFlag.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you better show us the c# code that is failing. And alongside that tell us what types are used. For example what type is f and what type is ImageItemFlag. And i mean what type your variables/properties have not what types are referenced.

Comment: You might want to try turning `Option Strict On` in your VB before trying to convert it.  It will make the type strictness much closer to C#.

Comment: If you have a variable with an `Enum` type, you can use `HasFlag` to do the test that is being done with `And` in the code.

Comment: @Craig I'm not programming this app in vb, just translating a sample from vb to c# (.net6.0), but I'll look into it.

Comment: If it's a sample, it's very unfortunate that it won't compile cleanly using `Option Strict On` (or so I presume given the failure observed with C#)---this is a commentary on the sample, not a commentary on anything you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the types of property and ImageItemFlag you may need to cast them as int.

```
using static WIA.WiaItemFlag; // enum


Device device;
CommonDialog dialog = new CommonDialog();
int i = 0;

device = dialog.ShowSelectDevice();

foreach (Item item in device.Items)
{
    var property = item.Properties["Item Flags"];
    // &-Operator can't be applied to Types 'Property' and WiaItemFlag
    if (((int)property & (int)ImageItemFlag).Equals(ImageItemFlag)) 
        i++;
}
```

Comment: property is of Type WIA.Property, and it can't be cast to a string (according to Intellisense)

Comment: can you add .ToString() to the end of property? (If that works you want to test property for null before doing that).

Comment: It compiles with ToString(), but how am i supposed to know if it is the correct result? It seems kinda ambiguous to me.

Comment: Can you give an example of what kind of value 'property' returns and what kind of value ImageItemFlag returns? I am starting to think that that 'property' is a set of values and you are trying to see if ImageItemFlag is within that set of values?

Comment: e.g. property.get_Value() returns 67 for my device... maybe that's the solution, though WiaItemFlag-Members seem to map to hex-values (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wiaaut/-wiaaut-wiaitemflag)

Comment: So why are you concatenating property and ImageItemFlag? Do you not just want to compare property to ImageItemFlag?

Comment: The original VB uses the bitwise `And`, so `&` is the correct C# translation.  The problem is a type/casting problem, not a choice of operator problem.

Comment: @craig, you you are right. I'll change my answer to reflect that and make the assumption the values are int based on his comment about getting 67 from get_Value().

Comment: @Mifo you can't cast a property to int either. Regarding your edit. Instead i cast property.get_Value() to int, though you can't operate with the &-Operator on ints